# Analysis of computer software performance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, multivariate-analysis, nonparametric

I am currently collecting data from a software system that draws conclusions about the nature of certain structures in medical CT chest scans. Structures in the chest can be classified into four types: $C_1=$ nodules, $C_2=$ attached nodules, $C_3=$ vessels, and $C_4=$ vessel branches. The software analyzes the CT scans and assigns a probability to each case. So for each test case the output is a set of four real numbers in the interval $[0,1]$, that is, each test case $a=\{C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4:C_i \in [0,1]\}$. We say that a test case is a "hit" if $\max\{a\}$ corresponds to the ground truth of the test case. For example, let $a$ be a test case with the ground truth of nodule and the software provides an output of $\{C_1=0.7546,C_2=0.2378,C_3=0.0967,C_4=0.0471\}$. Since $\max\{C_1=0.7546,C_2=0.2378,C_3=0.0967,C_4=0.0471\}=C_1$, we say that this test case is a hit.

Now, the question that I have is what sort of statistical analysis should be done on this system? I have a data set of 400 test cases of this form and I am not sure how to analyze and interpret the results. The data set is in no particular order, just a collection of these probabilities.

Comment: It may be helpful to define what the goal of your analysis is.